# Describe object property of variable

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I have code something like this:

```
var availableCondition = {
    property1: {
        condition: true,
        value: 'value1'
    },
    property2: {
        condition: false,
        value: 'value2'
    },
}
var obj = {}
for (var key in availableCondition) {
    var potentialProperty = availableCondition[key];
    if (potentialProperty ['condition']){
         obj[key] = potentialProperty['value']
    }
}
```

How can I describe var obj to have ability of IDE code implemention, something like in case

```
var obj = {
     property1: 'value1',
     property2: 'value2',
}
```

When I start type

```
obj.
```

IDE take me property completion in second way, but not in first.

How to describe object in jsDoc to have this completion?
[image: autocomplete example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

```
var availableCondition = {
    property1: {
        condition: true,
        value: 'value1'
    },
    property2: {
        condition: false,
        value: 'value2'
    },
};
/**
 *
 * @type {object}
 * @property {string} property1
 * @property {string} property2
 */
var myObj = {};
for (var key in availableCondition) {
    var potentialProperty = availableCondition[key];
    if (potentialProperty ['condition']){
        myObj[key] = potentialProperty['value']
    }
}
```

[image: right solution]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for.

```
var availableCondition = {
  property1: {
    condition: true,
    value: 'value1'
  },
  property2: {
    condition: false,
    value: 'value2'
  }
}

function createObj(obj) {
  var result = {};
  for (var key in obj) {
    result[key] = obj[key].value;
  }  
  return result;
}
console.log(createObj(availableCondition));
```

Comment: Not at all. Jetbrain IDE's can autocomplete object variable property. But without jsDoc it works only for static object.
Functon in answer allow me to copy my object into simplified with chosen properties.
But I need to use IDE autocomplete of any kind of objects.
I want to find a way how to correct describe object to enable this feature.